# Lightdm made me log in twice

Tags: login-screen

The second login screen is normal. But in the first login screen, I can't type any password to go through it and strange characters appear in the upper-left hand of the screen when I type.

Would appreciate any help greatly.

Comment: Try reinstalling `lightdm` just in case... `sudo apt-get purge lightdm && sudo apt-get install lightdm`, then restart.

Comment: Thank you, but the issue persists.

Comment: Have you done some recent change to your system which you might consider the cause of this?

Comment: See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1867733. Seems unresolved though..

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, so I removed lightdm (`sudo apt-get remove lightdm`) and reinstalled it after restarting my pc, which solved my problem. If it is still not working, open light-locker-settings and make sure *Enable light-locker* is off.